# Why does Array.splice(-1,1) remove last element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I was trying to remove certain elements based on their index in array.
example:

```
var x = ["a","b","c"];
```

and trying to do

```
x.splice(x.indexOf("d"),1)
```

Since this turns out to be `x.splice(-1,1)` - it's ending up removing the element "c" from the array!

unable to understand why this is happening even though there is no cyclic property for Arrays in javascript.

Comment: Have you [checked the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on how `splice` works?

Comment: Speficially to @ssube's link: "If negative, will begin that many elements from the end."

Answer (score 11):

From the [MDN page for `splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> If negative, will begin that many elements from the end.

So `x.splice(-1, 1)` starts one element from the end of `x` and deletes a single element.